# Hibernate Criteria query - Class cast exception

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am using Hibernate(3.2) Criteria for querying and its giving me exception when converting to a list.

Please see my code and exception below:

```
    List<Summary> summaryList;
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Summary.class);
    session.beginTransaction();
    summaryList = Criteria.setProjection(
      Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.sum("contractDollar"))
      .add(Projections.groupProperty("department"))).list() ;
```

exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.abc.model.Summary

I am not sure why the result is returned as 'Object' even though I specified it as my pojo(Summary)

Could you please help me with this. I am a newbie to hibernate.

Thanks,
Raja.

Comment: Have you specified a ResultTransformer ?

Answer (score 3):

Is `Summary` a mapped entity or a bean you're trying to return in your results? It shouldn't be both. You need to pass an entity class into `session.createCriteria()`.

As far as results go, you need to:

1. Have an appropriate setter in your Summary class (or your result bean if it's different).
2. Specify an alias for your projection.
3. Specify an 'aliasToBean' result transformer.

Your criteria code will become:

```
summaryList = Criteria.setProjection(
 Projections.projectionList()
  .add(Projections.sum("contractDollar"), "contractSum")
  .add(Projections.groupProperty("department"))
 )
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Summary.class))
.list() ;
```

Your `Summary` bean will need to have a `setContractSum()` method in this example.

Comment: Old question but this line is golden: `.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Summary.class))`

Comment: Getting this error: Could not instantiate resultclass

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `Summary` is but try:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Summary.class);
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
summaryList = criteria.setProjection(
    Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.sum("contractDollar"))
      .add(Projections.groupProperty("department"))).list() ;

Object[] result = criteria.list().get(0);
// result[0] holds the sum of contractDollar

tx.commit();
```